# Remove prefix from some values in a col in dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to standardize a column in a big dataframe where some values have the prefix "6016" and some don't. I need to remove all the "6016" prefixes but I don't know how to do so. I'm new to R, so sorry if this is simple.

Here's a snippet of the dataframe:

```
    A  
1   6016200703543489  
2   200726343459  
3   200403843687  
4   6016200784256494  
5   200704521983
```

I need this column to be like this, without affecting other columns:

```
    A  
1   200703543489  
2   200726343459  
3   200403843687  
4   200784256494  
5   200704521983
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can do:

```
sub("^6016", "", df$A)

[1] "200703543489" "200726343459" "200403843687" "200784256494" "200704521983"
```

Here it removes exactly `6016` from beginning of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

We can substring

```
df1$A <- substring(df1$A, nchar(df1$A) - 11, nchar(df1$A))
df1$A
#[1] "200703543489" "200726343459" "200403843687" "200784256494" "200704521983"
```

---

Or with `sub`

```
sub(".*(.{12})$", "\\1", df1$A)
#[1] "200703543489" "200726343459" "200403843687" "200784256494" "200704521983"
```

Both the methods work even if the prefix is different and is more general

If we need to remove the '6016'

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(df1$A, '^6016')
[#1] "200703543489" "200726343459" "200403843687" "200784256494" "200704521983"
```

---

Or another option is to create a new dataset manually

```
df1$A <- c("200703543489", "200726343459", "200403843687", 
          "200784256494", "200704521983")
```

NOTE: Showed 4 methods (general/exact/manual).

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(6016200703543489, 200726343459, 200403843687, 
6016200784256494, 200704521983)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```